# Counting distinct user id's from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have about 5 tables with common field “userid” I want to count distinct userids across all these tables. Certain user ids may occur in about 2 of these tables. But I want to count the UNION of distinct user ids in the 5 tables together. I am able to count distinct userids in one table with the ff code. I want to be able count from all tables.

```
//just count the nuber of distict userids in table1
    $query2 = ("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) FROM table1"); 
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2); 
    echo "Number of users in table 1  = ".$row2[0] ."<br />";


**Table 1**
Id    userid    name   adresss

**Table 2**
Id  Title   Sex   userid

**Table 3**
Id   userid   amount

**Table 4**
Id  price  promotion  userid   productid

**Table  5**
Id  userid   category   tax   weight
```

Comment: This looks like a standard table setup... why do you need to count over all these tables?  One would have assumed that you have a table generating unique `userId`s somewhere, that you can get the count out of (probably `Table 1`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `UNION`

A standard `UNION`, in contrast with a `UNION ALL`, will remove duplicate values from the resultset. Your statement would look like

```
SELECT   COUNT(*)
FROM     (
           SELECT UserID FROM Table1
           UNION SELECT UserID FROM Table2
           UNION SELECT UserID FROM Table3
           UNION SELECT UserID FROM Table4
           UNION SELECT UserID FROM Table5
         ) AS UserIDs
```

[From w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

> the UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow
>   duplicate values, use UNION ALL.

Comment: Kindly look at this tricky one for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503321/select-and-count-distinct-active-users-by-platform-and-compare-if-they-exist-in

Comment: @astymore - I just did, let us know if it is not what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks man, it works well. only syntax error (space btn COUNT and bracket)but works well.